# Replace text and insert more text

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to replace some text in a file and add couple of lines before the end of file.

I have this:

```
{
  "something": "option1",
  "other": [
    "value",
  ]
}
```

and I need this:

```
{
  "something": "option2",
  "other": [
    "value",
  ],
  "more": {
    "stuff": "yey!"
  }
}
```

I tried this scipt:

```
stuff=$1

value=",
  \"more\": {
    \"stuff\": \"$stuff\"
  }"

sed -e "s/option1/option2" -e '$ \i$value' \
  file1.json > file2.json
```

but I get:

```
{
  "something": "option2",
  "other": [
    "value",
  ]
$value
}
```

How do I do this properly?

Comment: single quotes are literal strings that don't expand variables

Comment: @Austin_Anderson I know that's why I'm getting this result, but don't know how to expand variable in this case... I tried different things, but this is the only one that doesn't throw error (;

Comment: also regex can't parse json, so if you need anything more than a one off, you need to use some json library, like in a perl or python script

Comment: what is the context? do you have like 50+ tiny json files that all look like your first box? is this part of a large json file? I'm assuming it's not just what you've posted or else you would have just typed it in manually

Comment: I want to modify configuration file like this, so I can run some more commands with modified version... It's a larger file, but it could be a simple text file. Question is how to insert text from variable one line before file end...

Comment: you can do `echo "$value" | sed -e 's/option1/option2/' -e '$r /dev/stdin' file1.json` with GNU sed, but you won't get the `,` to be added at end of second last line...

Answer (score 1):

The only right way to manipulate json data is using JSON parsers/processors. Period!

Use **`jq`** processor, it'll make your "relationship"  with JSON easy and comfortable:

Valid JSON `file1.json`:

```
{
  "something": "option1",
  "other": [
    "value"
  ]
}
```

---

```
stuff="jq got you"
jq --arg stuff "$stuff" '.more = {stuff: $stuff}' file1.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "something": "option1",
  "other": [
    "value"
  ],
  "more": {
    "stuff": "jq got you"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the better way, but if you want with sed, you can try

With gnu sed

```
echo "$value" | sed ':A;/\n.*}/!{N;bA};h;s/.*//;N;$!{s/.*\n//;:B;N;$!{H;s/option1/option2/;s/\n.*//p;g;s/\(.*\)\(\n.*\n[^\n]*\)/\1/;x;s/\(.*\n\)\([^\n]*\)/\2/;bB}};H;g;s/\(.*\n\)\([^\n]*\)\(\n[^\n]*\)/\2/;G;s/\(.*\n\)\([^\n]*\n\)\([^\n]*\)/\1\3/;s/\([^\n]\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\1\3/' /dev/stdin infile
```

Or with OpenBSD sed

```
cat scriptsed
sed ':A;/\n.*}/!{N;bA
}
h;s/.*//;N;$!{s/.*\n//;:B;N;$!{H;s/option1/option2/;s/\n.*//p;g;s/\(.*\)\(\n.*\n[^\n]*\)/\1/;x;s/\(.*\n\)\([^\n]*\)/\2/;bB
}
}
H;g;s/\(.*\n\)\([^\n]*\)\(\n[^\n]*\)/\2/;G;s/\(.*\n\)\([^\n]*\n\)\([^\n]*\)/\1\3/;s/\([^\n]\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\1\3/'
```

And call it like that

```
(echo "$value";cat infile) | ./scriptsed
```